# Memory allocation lookup

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I allocated memory:

```
int *p = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Then I typcase it:

```
char *new = (char *)p;
```

I deallocate it:

```
free(new);
```

1) How much memory will be deallocated as character has 1 byte of space?
2) what internal mechanism should a memory manager make (in embedded system) to keep track of allocated memory and deallocated memory? (no Boolean allowed)

Comment: `malloc()` and `free()` deal with `void* and have no idea about the type - they just deal with blocks of memory of the size you ask for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `malloc` (or one of it's siblings), the size of the memory allocate it stored as part of the 'information about this allocation' (`info_block`). `malloc` doesn't know if you passed in `sizeof(int)`, the constant `4` or `sizeof(short)*2` or whatever else you may have given it [actually, it may well expand the allocation to, say, 16 bytes - and this size is stored as part of the allocation.

When you later call `free`, it will "find back" the `info_block`, and then it knows the size to free. So, it doesn't matter what casts, or other manipulations you do on the pointer - as long as the pointer inside is the same value.

Comment: I want to avoid look ups, like I am writing a new memory managers and there are no undesired lookups/Boolean/size storage

Comment: The "lookup", in all allocators I've looked at, is as simple as "subtract sizeof(info) from the pointer we got", so it's not a long operation at all. Some allocators then tries to merge the previous/next block of free memory to the current one, but not always. If fragmentation is an issue, using a set of "buckets" of a fixed number of sizes is a good way to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

I your specific case, the answer depends on the underlying architecure. Assuming a 32-bit machine, the size of a pointer is always 4 bytes. It could get troublesome if you used, i.e.

```
int *p = (int *) malloc(sizeof(char));
```

but you'll get a warning, I believe.

So in your case it is 4 bytes that become allocated.

Additionally you should not cast the void* from malloc:

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

is perfectly fine.